# Filtration on columns created using CASE Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, having-clause

I have a table below:

```
id int
user_id int
created_at datetime
status varchar
type varchar
```

and I am trying to answer the question "Write a query that returns the user ID of all users that have created at least one ‘Refinance’ submission and at least one ‘InSchool’ submission."

I figured out how this will be done:

```
select
    a.user_id
from
    (select
        user_id,
        sum(
            case
                when type='Refinance' then 1 else 0 end) as "Refinancecount",
        sum(
            case
                when type='InSchool' then 1 else 0 end) as "Inschoolcount"
    from
        loans
    group by 1) as a
where a.Refinancecount>=1 and a.Inschoolcount>=1
```

When I run only the inner query, everything is fine. I am getting 3 columns but when I run the whole query it says column Refinancecount doesn't found.
I looked on internet and found when I am aliasing my case columns then I should't wrap them in double quotes and the query worked fine using this suggestion.
But I read more about creating columns using CASE in postgre, and found people do wrap column names in double quotes (I have attached an example screenshot)[image].
Then why my query doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote those fields in the `where` clause. Try:

```
where "Refinancecount" >= 1 and "Inschoolcount" >= 1
```

By the way, you can write this query without inner query, by using `having` clause:

```
select
        user_id
from
        loans
group by 1
having sum(case when type='Refinance' then 1 else 0 end) >=1 and sum(case when type='InSchool' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yea it's said  column Refinancecount doesn't found because you need to use quote `where a."Refinancecount">=1 and a."Inschoolcount">=1`. If you name your column as "Inschoolcount" you need to refer to it with the "" otherwise a.Refinancecount will be converted to a.refinancecount

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it simple like this

```
 select
    user_id
     from
    loans
   group by user_id having
   sum(
        case
            when type in ('Refinance', 
             'InSchool') then 1 else 0 end >=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT l1.user_id 
    from 
    loans l1
    join
    loans l2
where
    l1.type = 'Refinance'
and 
    l2.type = 'InSchool'
;
```